# I need to switch to second monitor while main monitor is not available

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop connected to a video projector but the computer is on the end of life and the main screen is not working fine anymore, most of the time there is nothing displayed.
So the video projector allows me to keep it as game console but while the computer respects the previous configuration to show on second screen only when it's starting, when it gets to the login screen, it ignores this configuration and I have to set it back with Windows+P.
But remember, the main screen is blank, I don't know what it displayed on it, so this is hell for me to get the right option.
I think the solution is to get/add a shortcut to set display configuration to "second screen only" by one hit.
Please, how to do that ? Have you any other solution for me ?

Answer (score 0):

If both the monitor and the projector uses the same cables, you can simply swap the cables to force the initial display to the projector.

If that is not an option, try setting the projector screen as your primary monitor when both screens are enabled, and then disable the main monitor.

Also, I'm fairly sure that you can just unplug the monitor and everything will work fine.